# Jersey Date/Time Serialization

Tags: java, json, jersey

I am populating a model object with a java.util.Date property in a web service.

I populate the model object with this Date in JDBC:

```
compRec.setEffDt(new java.util.Date(resultSet.getTimestamp("eff_dt").getTime()));
```

Selecting the row/col in my DB query (Oracle) tool, it shows

```
1999-01-13 21:55:00
```

After the object is created, the IDE debugger shows the type and contents properly as:

```
Date@5952: Jan 13 21:55:00 MST 1999
```

So, it seems to me that everything is intact at this point.  However, the Jersey client is serializing it to JSON as shown below, using the following JUnit test:

```
    @Test
public void getDetails0() {
    long value = 1L;
    try {
        int companyId = 333;
        Client client = Client.create();
        WebResource webResource = client.resource(webServiceTestBaseUri + implPath + "/data/" + companyId);
        CompanyGetDetails clientResponse = webResource.accept("application/json").type("application/json").get(CompanyGetDetails.class);
        System.out.println(clientResponse.toJson());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        value = -1L;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    assertEquals(1L, value);
}
```

However, on the Jersey side it looks like:

```
"effDt": "Wed Mar 28 04:42:25 MDT 132903212",
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate this in a short but complete program?

Comment: It would be hard to write a standalone, and include a model object, Connection, etc.  But I added some more actual code, that may provide more context.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't see why it should be hard to create a standalone example. All you need is a class with a single `Date` property - and you don't need to fetch it from anywhere, if the problem is in converting it to JSON... (If that's where the problem is, that sounds more like a Jackson issue than a Jersey issue.)